# Can't change the colors on a ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm working with a dataset of 5k finish times that looks a little bit like this:

```
"15:34"
"14:23"
"17:34"
```

and so on, there's a lot, but they're all formatted like that. I'm able to convert all of them to POSIXct, and store them in a data frame to make using ggplot2 easier, but for the life of me, I cannot get ggplot to change colors. The fill command doesn't work, the graph just remains grey.

I've tried just referencing the POSIXct object I made, but ggplot throws an error and tells me it doesn't work well with POSIXct. The only way I've been able to display a histogram is by storing it in a dataframe.

The code I'm currently using looks like:

```
#make the data frame
df <- data.frame(
finish_times = times_list)


#set the limits on the x axis as datetime objects
 lim <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c('2018-3-18 14:15', '2018-3-18 20:00'), format = "%Y-%m-%d %M:%S"))

#making the plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = finish_times)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = 'red') + #this just doesn't work
  stat_bin(bins = 30) + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%M:%S"),
                   breaks = date_breaks("1 min"),
                   limits = lim) +
  labs(title = "2017 5k finishers", 
       x='Finish Times',
       y= 'Counts')
```

I've crawled through a lot of ggplot and R documentation, and I'm not sure what I'm missing, I appreciate all help, thanks

Comment: Are you sure the ggplot code isn't throwing an error and just leaving up your last plot? `fill = "red"'` should work, e.g. try: `ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=rnorm(100)), fill = 'red')`

Comment: plotting packages have so many different pieces to them, it can be difficult to put things together from the documentation alone. A good place to start if you're new to ggplot would be http://r4ds.had.co.nz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stat_bin(bins = 30)` is overriding anything you set in `geom_histogram()`.  Generally, each geom has an associated default stat, and you can plot the object using one of the two, but when you try to do it with both, you can end up with problems.  There are several solutions to this. Here's an example.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "red") + stat_bin(bins = 30)
```

Produces a plot with gray fill

[image]

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "red", bins = 30)
```

Produces a plot with red fill

[image]

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for ever!

Comment: You're quite welcome :)  Feel free to upvote as well as accept this as an answer. I think you can do that now.

Comment: `stat_bin()` does not override the color when I try: `ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=rnorm(100)), fill = "red") + stat_bin(bins = 30) `

Comment: I'm guessing that's because you set a mapping value, with aes so that impacts how successive calls inherit, but you'd probably have to step through it with a browser to be sure